# Why does my browser get an image twice?

Tags: php

I have a php script which records an impression then displays an image.

```
// Determine which header to send. 
$parts = explode('.', $tool->filename);
header("Content-Type: image/{$parts[1]}");
readfile('files/'.$tool->filename);
```

For some reason Firefox is getting the file twice. Here is the log.

```
00:00:01.268    0.023   1211    182 GET 200 image/png   http://localhost/ap/image.php?aid=1&t=6
00:00:01.347    0.162   1185    182 GET 200 image/png   http://localhost/ap/image.php?aid=1&t=6
```

You can see they are got a split second apart. If I change the script as follows.

```
// Determine which header to send. 
$parts = explode('.', $tool->filename);
//header("Content-Type: image/{$parts[1]}");
//readfile('files/'.$tool->filename);
echo 1;
```

Then the browser only reads the file once. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: My guess is because you're calling header and readfile

Comment: @SandeepBansal That doesn't seem reasonable; the header is just setting the content type.

Comment: You shouldn't be finding the content type by extension. Instead use the [`Fileinfo`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) PECL extension.

Comment: I can't recreate this issue with PHP `readfile`ing an image out. Mac OS X 10.7 with Chrome 21.0.1180.57 and Firefox 12.0.

Comment: Can we see the HTML source where the image is displayed? *Edit* actually, is this loaded from HTML or just when visiting the image URL directly in the address bar? If the latter, see [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=304574)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing purposes try starting your firefox from a console via

```
firefox -safe-mode -no-remote
```

to temporarily disable all extension. Maybe one of the extensions is causing this.

Comment: Agreed. Firebug itself tends to load some resources twice.